# Chinese characters showing as?

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, symbols

I have an issue of showing Chinese characters, look at these 2 pages.
http://www.wufangsingapore.com/instructor-junbeng.php

http://www.wufangsingapore.com/schedule.php

You will realised that the first link which I linked didn't have any issues with the Chinese characters while my second one is showing as ??? despite the fact that it is showing fine in cPanel. Both pages' charset in the meta tag are set to "charset=utf-8" which is supposed to be right. What could be the issue?

Both of them are just pure html, even though they are in PHP extension, they are not reading from any database.

Thanks!

Comment: the ??? are not Chinese characters being rendered badly on the browser they are three question mark characters. Your generating code is creating them.
Before I worked this out I did check all the HTTP headers in fiddler and the HTML encoding, which are both identical

Comment: I did tried to copy the chinese text i have on the first link onto the second link, its showing fine in the notepad / web designer but it went bad when i view from the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHile I didn't figure out what really happened.

This is what i did to make the chinese characters appear.

1. Open up the file in cPanel's File Manager and copy the whole chunk of PHP/HTML code onto the notepad
2. Save the notepad file as the file name again schedule.php
3. Reupload via Windows Explorer FTP.